# Get the reflection of a POINT M[row][col] on a SQUARE matrix M, of size N

Tags: matrices, rotations, reflection

I have the following 7 x 7 matrix, which I'll name M. It has a value of 1 at M[2,2].

```
       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

If I rotate the matrix 180 degrees I would get the REFLECTION of the matrix, and 1 would be now at M[4,4].

```
       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I'm looking for a formula to find the **REFLECTION OF A POINT** on a square matrix without doing the actual 180 degree rotation to get the result. A function to which I could pass **f(M[2,2])**, and get **f(M[4,4])**. This function should *map **M[row][col]** to **M[reflected_row][reflected_col]*** for ALL the points that could have a reflection on a SQUARE matrix of size N.

Thanks

p.s. I using python with numpy

Comment: You should ask this on Stack Overflow instead if you want the code for it. Or do you want a mathematical function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mathematical function that does the trick is simply

$$f:M_{i,j} \mapsto M_{N-i,N-j},$$

but perhaps you are looking for a function in Python that does this? In that case, either simply define it yourself or ask over at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Wow, that's what I was looking for. Does this function have a formal name after which it is known in the field? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @OantaWilliamRichard Glad it was helpful! Hmm, I don't know the name, perhaps it doesn't even have one - I just sat down with a drawing and found that this one would do the trick :)